# master-slave and slave-master

Tags: postgresql

One of the steps for setting up a master-slave is to do **pg_basebackup** on the slave from the master.

So let's suppose I have a master and a slave. So if my master is down for 30 mins, I convert my slave to a Master. Now after 30 min I want my previous master to be up as a slave with all the updated records. But I don't want to move the **data** of the previous master to another location and then use pg_basebackup to get the data at the same place.

Is there any way with which we can update the existing **data** of the previous master rather than overriding it?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is exactly what [pg_rewind](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrewind.htm) is for.  (Never used it myself)

Comment: I have read about Pg_rewind what it does is it synchronises timeline of main and replica by deleting records if inserted on main after promoting replica. So I want to know if I have updates on my new master does it sync with my new replica(which was old master)?